# Get data of all rows and extract input values, tr.data() of td.data() attritubes

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am trying to use DataTables and trying to see if i can get it implemented onto my site.

I've tried searching the DataTables and Stack Overflow forums and Googling, but haven't found anything yet that answers my question. Probably I've read over it somewhere, but I am hoping someone will help me.

Case

- a large number or table rows with 10 inputs on every table row (tr)
- what i need: to get all the input values for every row (visible or not) WITH the `tr.data()` and/or `td.data()` that might be set for that row.

Right now I am using this:

```
$('#example').DataTable().rows().data().toArray()
```

and getting this for every row:

```
["<input type=\"text\" value=\"0\">", "<input type=\"text\" value=\"0\">", "<input type=\"text\" value=\"0\">", "<input type=\"text\" value=\"0\">", "<input type=\"text\" value=\"0\">"]
```

a) I don't see the data() attribute that was attached to that row, how to get it?

b) how can I get the value of for instance row 0, first input? In jQuery I would use `$('tr').first().find('input').val()` or give it an id but how can I do something like that with the DataTables output? looking at what the above output gives me, i have no idea yet how to accomplish that. (So for all rows, not only the visible ones)

Not every row is in the DOM, so there must an object or something holding all table rows from where I can extract the value for every input on every table row and also get their data() attribute.

Comment: Hi, can you show sample html code as well .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you are familiar with approaches such as jQuery's `$('tr').first().find('input').val()`.

To use something like that, you can use the following:

```js
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx ) {
  var firstVal = $( this.node() ).first().find('input').val();
  console.log( 'Row ' + (rowIdx+1)  + ' first value: ' + firstVal );
} );
```

Here, we [iterate over every row](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) in the DataTable regardless of whether the row is on the currently displayed page, or not. This means we access data which is in the DataTable, but which may not be displayed in the DOM.

We get a node object using [`row().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()) and then use that in a jQuery selector.

My test table:

```
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="X"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Y"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Z"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="D"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="E"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="F"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="P"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Q"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="R"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My DataTable:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  "lengthMenu": [ 2 ] // just to force 2 pages of data
} );
```

The console output:

```
Row 1 first value: X
Row 2 first value: D
Row 3 first value: P
```

You can obviously improve this to use jQuery to process every field in each node - not just the first field.

---

The order in which the rows are iterated is based on the current display order (i.e. taking sorting into account).

You can also iterate the data based on the original load order of the data:

```
table.rows( {order: 'index'} ).every( ... );
```

This causes the internally assigned DataTables row index to be used. This index value does not change when data is sorted.

See [selector modifiers](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) for details.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for this, very helpful! i am very happy with this. Datables is very powerful. I am working with your suggestions and demo and i think this solves my problem. Next on the list is finding out how to add two checkboxes to every line which upon loading data through ajax can be turned on or off and which the user can turn on or off. interesting :-) thanks very much!

Comment: Ok i tested your sollution and although it works nicely, i notice that it only gets the values that are in the visible rows. I need to get both the values and the data attributes for every line. so, if i have 1000 lines from the DB but there are only 50 rows visible, i still need to get the data (in an array) from the total 1000 lines, not only from the 50 visible rows. Could you please help me with this? i am googling and looking at the DataTables website but still...nothing that works for me.

Comment: Interesting. In my answer I create 3 rows - and then I force pagination - `"lengthMenu": [ 2 ]` - specifically to demonstrate that point (it was something you mentioned in the question, also). To help you, I would need a [mre]. So, for example, here is my MRE for my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/azj2wkeL/

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is: If you are using ajax (asynchronous!) and/or handling a large volume of data, then make sure your table has finished rendering before attempting to extract data. Here is a fiddle showing how to do that using `initComplete`: https://jsfiddle.net/pvawbhjm/

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for the late response...i fell asleep....

Here is a my fiddle, if you look at the console you'll see what i mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dave33/dusLk324/13/

Hopefully you can see what i'm doing wrong here... 
Also, can i get the data attribute of the row as well via what i am doing now or do i need to do something else? (i normally do tr.data() but now i presume a variable must have the data attribute of rows that aren't in the visible table?)

Comment: Also, no ajax used in this example but yes i'll do what you said. i normally do that already without DataTables but it's good to know how to do that with DataTables. It makes me very happy that you want to share your knowledge!

Comment: I've been looking into it and it seems to be related to the deferRender:true init option. I've turned it off and now ALL rows (not only the first 108 in my case) and their values and data() attributes can be logged out into the console using table.rows( { order: 'index' }).every(function(rowIdx) { ... Trying to work out if the consequence for not including this option is nasty. Looking at https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender atm. It has to work through ajax. I've got it working without DataTables and now i want to substitute that code with DataTables functionality.

Comment: Looks like you solved the problem - nice! Did you have a specific reason to use `deferRender`? If not, then you can safely remove it.

Comment: Looks like it :-) thank you very much for your help and thinking with me. no, no specific reason. i took an example off of the DataTables site and it was there so i left it there. as far as i can see now i don't need it so i've removed it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `children()`. this must be return all td of tr.

if you want more help please give more information for your code

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it wasn't the right one for me. Thanks for trying!